# Pdf generation for dynamic contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, pdf-generation, quartz-graphics

i am generating pdf report in my app,When the page contents exceeds over one page how to populate the contents,actually in this situation i tried to create one more new page by giving CGContextBeginPage();
but it is showing error like

: CGContextEndPage: Don't nest calls to this function -- the results will not be what you expect.
********** : CGContextBeginPage: Don't nest calls to this function -- the results will not be what you expect.

Can somebody tell me how to create pdf during this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a variable that stores your current Y position as you are laying out content, incrementing this value by the height of the content (and any padding).

Each time you want to render some text or image etc, check that you have enough space on the page before rendering and if not end the current page and begin a new one. Check the space by looking at the current Y position, adding the content height to it and comparing to your page rect.

The errors you are getting are due to you nesting PDF page calls, the OS expects the following approach...

```
CGContextBeginPage
... render content for page 1
CGContentEndPage

CGContextBeginPage
... render content page 2
CGContentEndPage
```

However your code is most likely nesting these as follows...

```
CGContextBeginPage
... render content for page 1
CGContextBeginPage
... render content for page 2
CGContextEndPage
CGContextEndPage
```

Comment: Hello Lee
Thanks,i fixed that issue,the page is created but nothing is written in that page,the below shown is the code what i am using to end and create new page
 if(y<=40){    y=700;
 CGContextRestoreGState(pdfContext);
 UIGraphicsPopContext(); CGContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &pageRect);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
CGContextSaveGState(pdfContext);
 }
const char *str=[@"SO" UTF8String];                       CGContextShowTextAtPoint(pdfContext,x,y,str,strlen(str));
x=x+50;
please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance